# Jsoup select text WITH including html tags

Tags: java, android, html, textview, jsoup

I use Jsoup to select some code between `<td></td>` tags. It looks like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response, "UTF-8");

Element elMotD = doc.select("td.info").first();
String motdText = elMotD.text();
```

My problem now is that jsoup selects the text like I want but it simply sorts out tags like `<br>` which are important for my displaying in Android TextView later.

How can I do this that Jsoup doesn't miss the tags in between this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Use the [Element.html()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#html%28%29) method to get to the html including its inner html tags. You can also use [Node.outerHtml()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#outerHtmll%28%29) to the the html including the outer tags.

In your case:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response, "UTF-8");

Element elMotD = doc.select("td.info").first();
String motdHtml = elMotD.html();
```